# Use glstm(Group LSTM) cell to build bidirectional rnn in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, ocr

I'm using a cnn + lstm + ctc network (based on https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.05717.pdf) to do a Chinese scene text recognition. For a large number of classes (3500+), the network is very hard to train. I heard that using Group LSTM (https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.10722, O. Kuchaiev and B. Ginsburg "Factorization Tricks for LSTM Networks", ICLR 2017 workshop.) can reduce the number of parameters and accelerate the training, so I've tried to use it in my code.

I use a two-layers bidirectional lstm. This is the original code that using tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell

```
rnn_outputs, _, _ = 
tf.contrib.rnn.stack_bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(
[tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_units=self.num_hidden, state_is_tuple=True) for _ in range(self.num_layers)],
[tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_units=self.num_hidden, state_is_tuple=True) for _ in range(self.num_layers)], 
self.rnn_inputs, dtype=tf.float32, sequence_length=self.rnn_seq_len, scope='BDDLSTM')
```

The training is very slow. After 100 hrs, the prediction acc on the test set is still 39%.

Now I want to use tf.contrib.rnn.GLSTMCell. When I replace the LSTMCell with this GLSTMCell like

```
rnn_outputs, _, _ = tf.contrib.rnn.stack_bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(
[tf.contrib.rnn.GLSTMCell(num_units=self.num_hidden, num_proj=self.num_proj, number_of_groups=4) for _ in range(self.num_layers)],
[tf.contrib.rnn.GLSTMCell(num_units=self.num_hidden, num_proj=self.num_proj, number_of_groups=4) for _ in range(self.num_layers)],
self.rnn_inputs, dtype=tf.float32, sequence_length=self.rnn_seq_len, scope='BDDLSTM')
```

I get the following error

```
/home/frisasz/miniconda2/envs/dl/bin/python "/media/frisasz/DATA/FSZ_Work/deep learning/IDOCR_/work/train.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/frisasz/DATA/FSZ_Work/deep learning/IDOCR_/work/train.py", line 171, in <module>
    train(train_dir='/media/frisasz/Windows/40T/', val_dir='../../0000/40V/')
  File "/media/frisasz/DATA/FSZ_Work/deep learning/IDOCR_/work/train.py", line 41, in train
    FLAGS.momentum)
  File "/media/frisasz/DATA/FSZ_Work/deep learning/IDOCR_/work/model.py", line 61, in __init__
    self.logits = self.rnn_net()
  File "/media/frisasz/DATA/FSZ_Work/deep learning/IDOCR_/work/model.py", line 278, in rnn_net
    self.rnn_inputs, dtype=tf.float32, sequence_length=self.rnn_seq_len, scope='BDDLSTM')
  File "/home/frisasz/miniconda2/envs/dl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/ops/rnn.py", line 220, in stack_bidirectional_dynamic_rnn
    dtype=dtype)
  File "/home/frisasz/miniconda2/envs/dl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 375, in bidirectional_dynamic_rnn
    time_major=time_major, scope=fw_scope)
  File "/home/frisasz/miniconda2/envs/dl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 574, in dynamic_rnn
    dtype=dtype)
  File "/home/frisasz/miniconda2/envs/dl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 737, in _dynamic_rnn_loop
    swap_memory=swap_memory)
  File "/home/frisasz/miniconda2/envs/dl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2770, in while_loop
    result = context.BuildLoop(cond, body, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
  File "/home/frisasz/miniconda2/envs/dl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2599, in BuildLoop
    pred, body, original_loop_vars, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
  File "/home/frisasz/miniconda2/envs/dl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2549, in _BuildLoop
    body_result = body(*packed_vars_for_body)
  File "/home/frisasz/miniconda2/envs/dl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 720, in _time_step
    skip_conditionals=True)
  File "/home/frisasz/miniconda2/envs/dl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 206, in _rnn_step
    new_output, new_state = call_cell()
  File "/home/frisasz/miniconda2/envs/dl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 708, in <lambda>
    call_cell = lambda: cell(input_t, state)
  File "/home/frisasz/miniconda2/envs/dl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py", line 180, in __call__
    return super(RNNCell, self).__call__(inputs, state)
  File "/home/frisasz/miniconda2/envs/dl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 441, in __call__
    outputs = self.call(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/frisasz/miniconda2/envs/dl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/ops/rnn_cell.py", line 2054, in call
    R_k = _linear(x_g_id, 4 * self._group_shape[1], bias=False)
  File "/home/frisasz/miniconda2/envs/dl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py", line 1005, in _linear
    "but saw %s" % (shape, shape[1]))
ValueError: linear expects shape[1] to be provided for shape (?, ?), but saw ?

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'm not sure if the GLSTMCell can simply replace the LSTMCell in tf.contrib.rnn.stack_bidirectional_dynamic_rnn() (or other functions that help to build the rnn). I didn't find any examples of the use of GLSTMCell. Anybody know the right way to build a bidirectional rnn with GLSTMCell?

Answer (score 1):

I got the exact same error trying to build bidirectional GLSTM using bidirectional_dynamic_rnn.

In my case, the problem came from the fact that GLSTM can only be used when defined in a static way : when the graph is computed you can't have undefined shape parameters (such as batch_size for instance).

So, try to define in the graph all the shapes that will end up at some point in the GLSTM cell and it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks, I decided not to use glstm. I sped up the training by another way.